# How can I find the progress needed to next level with this code?

Tags: javascript, math

Looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56918073/progress-bar-for-leveling-system) but the way I handle progress is different.

`const curLevel = Math.floor(0.2 * Math.sqrt(number));`

For example, if number was `271`, I'd get the square root of 271 (`16.462`) and then times by `0.2` to give me `3.292` which we then round up to make the level `3`.

What I need to calculate is the amount needed to get to level 4 from level 3, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use algebra inversion rules to get `number` from `curLevel`:

```
curLevel === 0.2 * Math.sqrt(number) // Multiply by 5
5 * curLevel === Math.sqrt(number) // Square
(5 * curLevel) ** 2 === number
```

Level 4 needs `(5 * 4) ** 2 === 400` progress points.

From level 3 to level 4 you need `(5 * 4) ** 2 - (5 * 3) ** 2 === 175` points.

When having 271 points, getting to level 4 requires `(5 * 4) ** 2 - 271 === 129` points.